# Creating a new Queue using Spring AMQP on web application startup

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to create a new queue in RabbitMQ using Spring AMQP on server startup of my web application. I am not getting the exact configuration code how to achieve it.
Below is my code snippet. Please correct the following.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

     @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
            CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("10.165.18.29");
            connectionFactory.setUsername("User");
            connectionFactory.setPassword("user");
            return connectionFactory;
        }

     @Bean
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
            container.addQueueNames("create.queue");
            container.setMessageListener(exampleListener());
            return container;
        }

     @Bean
        public MessageListener exampleListener() {
            return new MessageListener() {
                public void onMessage(Message message) {
                    System.out.println("received: " + message);
                }
            };
        }
}
```

Comment: have you added a `RabbitAdmin` in your config?

Comment: whatever above code is my configuration. i haven't added any `RabbitAdmin` in my configuration. Please let me know how to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration).

Simply add `<rabbit:queue ... />` beans and a `<rabbit:admin ... />` and the admin will automatically declare the queues when the connection is first established.